# Must the fb:admins metatag be added to the <head> section of EVERY page of a website/domain, or ONLY the homepage (root)?

Tags: metadata, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

A question regarding the implementation of Facebook Insights metatags.

Must the fb:admins metatag be added to the `<head>` section of **EVERY** page of a website/domain, or **ONLY** the homepage (root)?

The [Insights documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) seems clear:

> Website owners must add a verification metatag to the `<head>` section
>   of the root webpage of a domain.

However, I've checked a number of major sites (Sydney Morning Herald, NY Times, Guardian, Mashable) and implementation varies.

Several sites have neither the fb:admins tag nor the fb:app_id on their homepage, but use at least one of the tags on the following pages.

On other sites, both tags are present on ALL pages.

So...

- Should the fb:admins tag be added only to the homepage, or to ALL
  pages?
- Is it a problem if the fb:admins tag is on all pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends.

If you just want access to Insights for Domains, it just has to be in the root page. This is so Facebook can ping http://www.example.com/ and give insights access to the users listed there.

If you're using Open Graph, you'll want this tag on every URL which could possibly end up in the Open Graph (like buttons, custom actions etc) so that you're listed as the admin of those objects.

In addition, I don't recommend using the fb:admins tag at all. Instead, I suggest you create an application, and add an fb:app_id containing your app id. This is so that, as the people in your site or organisation change, you just add them or remove them from the developer roles of your application, and they'll gain or lose access to be an admin of your domain. Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck with the user IDs you add on day one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We don't have an app, nor are we likely to have one in the near future, so fb:admins will have to do.  Why would we be unable to change the admins after day one?  I was planning to add the user id's of the three people who, well, admin our FB page.

Comment: in that case, use fb:page_id and the admins of your page will get access to insights for domains.

Comment: So, it turns out I forgot to add the Facebook and OpenGraph nameservers to my webpage, which is why we can't get Insights to work. Unfortunately, we can only do web releases once every 2 months for our site.  I'm not sure if we should stick with fb:page_id or change to fb:admins.  Due to my release restrictions, would it cause problems if I added BOTH??  Just to be sure??